# How can I stop purchase notification acknowledgement requests for cancelled purchase in Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

I didn't receive a purchase notification from Google Play (due to a fault on my own platform) so, correctly, after 3 minutes the purchase was cancelled.  That's fine.

However, the platform continues to send me notifications but complains (with a message 400) that the acknowledgement I send is faulty because "The product purchase is not owned by the user."

I can't cancel the purchase through the Developer Console, because it's already cancelled.

How can I stop the purchase notifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a satisfactory answer, but **an** answer is "don't worry too much about it, it will only run for a week".

Unless the Developer Console helpdesk have actioned it for me without letting me know, it eventually times out.  The notifications have stopped after about six days and twenty-three hours.

Let me know if you find any different :)